# Attaching author tag to the comment

Tags: comments, author

I have found how to highlight comments made by author of the post. However, could not achieve to attach simple text saying this is author for each comment replied by the author of the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can compare user_id to the author id, an then add your text.

```
global $post;
if ( $comment->user_id === $post->post_author ) { echo 'Author'; }
```

Comment: Thanks. This did not produce any output.

Comment: where did you insert it ?

Comment: Inside of theme/library/functions/comments.php file where the actual comments are being pulled from.

Comment: i added global $post; to my answear, check and tell me if it change something.
ps : also, check the output html to see if present or not ;)

Comment: You welcome, dont hesitate to valide the answear !